# How to get menubar directly under image?

Tags: jquery, css, menubar

OMG, this is seriously killing me now.  Been trying for hours now:  http://www.opportunityfinance.net/Test/conference-2013/index.html

No matter what I do, this darn menubar will not fit directly underneath of the top image!

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I've been playing with Google's inspector for different css styles, but I'm baffled, cause nothing works.  I am even trying to grab the value from the images `.height()` on resize and triggering this on load, but still when I do `position: absolute; top: ImgHeight` it doesn't put it just under the image.  There's no padding or margins under the image that I can tell.

What is going on here?

Comment: whats the top image cause the link provided shows "one purpose" in the upper left with stripes on the right, with a menubar underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ul` in the `nav` part has a `margin-top` of 27 px, that seems to be the problem.

Besides that, the div with `#header_image` is 6px bigger than the image inside (which causes a white space below the image).

Comment: How is that happening??  I don't have anything set for `margin-top` in the css rules for the `ul` weird!!  I have `line-height` set to `3em`, could that be causing it?

Comment: It can be one of your Javascript plugins or default CSS styles (applied by the browser). If you set it to 0 in your CSS, does that solve your problem?

Comment: Setting `margin` and/or `padding` to 0 does not help at all.

Comment: And when you add !important? (like this: `margin: 0px !important;`)

Comment: When I add `margin: 0px` to `ul.menu` (line 284 of index.css), the problem is solved. There is only a small white space, caused by the height of the image.

Comment: Ohh, yes, you're right, that does work for ul.menu, but how to get rid of the rest?  OMG...

Comment: Don't set a height to the div that contains the image. The div will take over the height of the image.

Comment: There is no height being set on the div that contains the image, there's just a height of `auto` on the actual image.

Comment: Could it be because of the `overflow:hidden` on the `div.header`??

Comment: No, I see. `Overflow: hidden` isn't causing the problem. Add `margin-top: -6px` to the `ul.menu` then. Not the most nice solution, but I get the idea the you're using code you don't understand 100% ;-)

Comment: lol, I can't use pixel value, it must be in `em` units, otherwise, when the browser gets resized, that gap will just show up again.

Comment: `-0.2em` is enough for me, but check it with different screen widths..

Comment: I wanted to add a mobile-friendly menubar and saw one, but my site is using adaptive and responsive design, so it's not exactly a copy and paste into the current stylesheet if you know what I mean.  Thanks for your help, `margin-top: -0.3em;` is the actual size.

Comment: I'll still need to work out the mobile-friendly part...lol, but atleast I have it computer browser-friendly Now ;)